# Compute the double value nearest preferred decimal result

Tags: javascript, floating-point, double

Let N(x) be the value of the decimal numeral with the fewest significant digits
such that x is the `double` value nearest the value of the numeral.

Given `double` values a and b, **how can we compute the `double` value nearest N(b)-N(a)?**

*E.g.:*

- If a and b are the `double` values nearest .2 and .3,

  - the desired result is the `double` value nearest .1,

    - 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625,
  - rather than than the result of directly subtracting a and b,

    - 0.09999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375.

Comment: Convert to 'integers' by multiplying then dividing by a power of 10: `(10*.3 - 10*.2) / 10 == 0.1`

Comment: @tom: Which power of ten? Specifically, given a and b, how can you compute which power of ten to use?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Perhaps convert to a string and look for the longest consecutive sequence of 9's or 0's???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a baseline: In Java, the `Double.toString()` provides the N(x) function described in the question, returning its value as a numeral. One could take the strings for a and b, subtract them with the elementary-school method, and convert the resulting string to `double`.

This demonstrates solving the problem is quite feasible using existing library routines. This leaves the task of improving the solution. I suggest exploring:

- Is there a function D(x) that returns the number of significant digits after the decimal place for the numeral described in N(x)? If so, can we multiply a and b by a power of ten determined by D(a) and D(b), round as necessary to produce the correct integer results (for situations where they are representable as `double` values), subtract them, and divide by the power of ten?
- Can we establish criteria for which `b-a` or some simple expression can be quickly rounded to something near a decimal numeral, bypassing the code that would be necessary for harder cases? E.g., could we prove that for numbers within a certain range, `(round(10000*b)-round(10000*a))/10000` always produces the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to 'integers' by multiplying then dividing by a power of ten:

```
(10*.3 - 10*.2)/10 == 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

It may be possible to work out the appropriate power of ten from the string representation of the number. @PatriciaShanahan suggests looking for repeated 0's or 9's.

Consider using a BigDecimal library such as [javascript-bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum) instead.

Comment: Most `double` values near numerals such as 3.14 have bits set in or near the low bit of the significand, so they cannot be multiplied by more than a small power of 10 before encountering rounding errors. E.g., `10*3.14` is not ten times the value of `3.14`.

Comment: You could use `Math.pow(10,Math.max ("".split.call(a,".")[1].length,"".split.call(b,".")[1].length))` to get the desired power of 10. The point is, is there a prove that this yields **always** the desired result or is there **any** 2 values, where this does not apply?

Answer (score 0):

You could also inquire in Smalltalk Pharo 2.0 where your request translates:

```
^(b asMinimalDecimalFraction - a asMinimalDecimalFraction) asFloat
```

Code could be found as attachment to issue 4957 at code.google.com/p/pharo/issues - alas, dead link, and the new bugtracker requires a login...

https://pharo.fogbugz.com/f/cases/5000/Let-asScaledDecimal-use-the-right-number-of-decimals

source code is also on github, currently:

https://github.com/pharo-project/pharo-core/blob/6.0/Kernel.package/Float.class/instance/printing/asMinimalDecimalFraction.st

The algorithm is based on:

Robert G. Burger and R. Kent Dybvig
Printing Floating Point Numbers Quickly and Accurately
ACM SIGPLAN 1996 Conference on Programming Language Design and Implementation
June 1996.
http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/FP-Printing-PLDI96.pdf