# When does appending an 'f' change the value of a floating constant when assigned to a `float`?

Tags: c, floating-point

Applying an `f` to a floating point constant does not seem to make a difference when assigning the constant to a `float`.

```
int main(void) {
  float f;
  //  1 2345678901234567
  f = 3.1415926535897932;
  printf("%.6a  %.8f  pi 3.1415926535897932\n", f, f);
  f = 3.1415926535897932f;              // v
  printf("%.6a  %.8f  pi 3.1415926535897932f\n", f, f);
}
```

With or without the `f`, the value is the same

```
// value       value          code 
0x1.921fb6p+1  3.14159274  pi 3.1415926535897932
0x1.921fb6p+1  3.14159274  pi 3.1415926535897932f
```

Why ever use `f`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a self answer per [Answer Your Own Question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Appending an `f` makes the constant a `float` and *sometimes* makes a value difference.

---

**Type**

Type difference: `double` to `float`.

A well enabled compiler may emit a warning when the `f` is omitted too.

```
  float f = 3.1415926535897932;  // May generate a warning
```

> warning: conversion from 'double' to 'float' changes value from '3.1415926535897931e+0' to '3.14159274e+0f' [-Wfloat-conversion]

---

**Value**

To make a *value* difference in the assignment, watch out for potential [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) issues.

The first rounding is due to code's text being converted to the floating point type.

> the result is either the nearest representable value, or the larger or smaller representable value immediately adjacent to the nearest representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner. C17dr § 6.4.4.2 3

Given those two choices, a *very common* implementation-defined manner is to convert the source code text to the closest `double` (without the `f`) or to the closest `float` with the `f` suffix.  Lesser quality implementations sometimes form the 2nd closest choice.

Assignment of a `double` FP constant to a `float` incurs another rounding.

> If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner. C17dr § 6.3.1.4 2

A *very common* implementation-defined manner is to convert the `double` to the closest `float` - with ties to even.  (Note: compile time rounding may be affected by various compiler settings.)

**Double rounding value change**

Consider the case when source code uses a value *very close* to half-way between 2 `float` values.

Without an `f`, the rounding of code to a `double` may result in a value exactly half-way between 2 `float`s.  The conversion of the `double` to `float` then could differ from "with an `f`".

With an `f`, the conversion results in the closest `float`.

Example:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  float f;
  f = 10000000.0f;
  printf("%.6a  %.3f  10 million\n", f, f);
  f = nextafterf(f, f + f);
  printf("%.6a  %.3f  10 million - next float\n", f, f);
  puts("");
  f = 10000000.5000000001;
  printf("%.6a  %.3f  10000000.5000000001\n", f, f);
  f = 10000000.5000000001f;
  printf("%.6a  %.3f  10000000.5000000001f\n", f, f);
  puts("");
  f = 10000001.4999999999;
  printf("%.6a  %.3f  10000001.4999999999\n", f, f);
  f = 10000001.4999999999f;
  printf("%.6a  %.3f  10000001.4999999999f\n", f, f);
}
```

Output

```
0x1.312d00p+23  10000000.000  10 million
0x1.312d02p+23  10000001.000  10 million - next float

// value        value         source code
0x1.312d00p+23  10000000.000  10000000.5000000001
0x1.312d02p+23  10000001.000  10000000.5000000001f // Different, and better

0x1.312d04p+23  10000002.000  10000001.4999999999
0x1.312d02p+23  10000001.000  10000001.4999999999f // Different, and better
```

**Rounding mode**

The issue about double<sup>1</sup> rounding is less likely when the rounding mode is up, down or towards zero.  Issue arises when the 2nd rounding compounds the direction on half-way cases.

**Occurrence rate**

Issue occurs when code converts inexactly to a `double` that is very near half-way between 2 `float` values - so relatively rare.  Issue applies even if the code constant was in decimal or hexadecimal form.  With random constants: about 1 in 2<sup>30</sup>.

**Recommendation**

Rarely a major concern, yet an `f` suffix is better to get the best value for a `float` and quiet a warning.

**[Update 2022]**

The issue is further complicated under 2 conditions:

- `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2`, then the constant maybe evaluated using `long double` math.
- Evaluation of floating point constants may ignore decimal digits past a certain precision.  This is allowed in C and IEEE 754.  Typically this is `XXX_DECIMAL_DIG + 3` digits (e.g. 20 for `double`).

These complications change the chance of seeing this issue.  Still the conclusion remains: append `f` to get the best `float` constant.

---

<sup>1</sup> *double* here refers to doing something twice, not the the type `double`.

Answer (score 1):

As a small addendum to [chux's answer](/a/66631298) is an example of something that can be perplexing: we assign a value to a float, and then immediately compare the float to the value and find they are not equal!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DCN 0.7
#define FCN 0.7f

int main(void)
{
    float f = DCN;
    const char* cf = (f == DCN) ? "equal" : (f > DCN) ? "greater" : (f < DCN) ? "less" : "???" ;
    printf("DCN\t%s\n", cf);

    float g = FCN;
    const char* cg = (g == FCN) ? "equal" : (g > FCN) ? "greater" : (g < FCN) ? "less" : "???" ;
    printf("FCN\t%s\n", cg);
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
DCN less
FCN equal
```

On the other hand if the constants are replaced with `0.1` and `0.1f` I get:

```
DCN more
FCN equal
```

Comment: This is the usual problem of comparing a `float` to a `double`.  On the other hand, if code was comparing a `float` to a `float` via `float g = DCN; printf("%d\n", g == FCN);` , then the result may be 0 for select constants and does help demo the title question.