# Why doesn't Clang-tidy detect a narrowing conversion from float to uint8_t in a function call?

Tags: c, type-conversion, static-code-analysis, clang-tidy, narrowing

We just caught a tiny bug that I would have expected Clang-Tidy to catch for us, so please let me know if this isn't expected behavior. We have the following piece of code

```
float value = 3.4f;   // 

result = function(&a, b, c, value);
```

Where value in the function definition is defined as a `uint8_t`:

```
uint8_t function(float* a, uint8_t b, float c, uint8_t value);
```

So we placed a float in a `uint8_t`, which casts it to integers, but somehow clang-tidy didn't find a problem with this. Are we using it wrong or doesn't it detect `uint8_t`'s, just ints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you enable `PedanticMode`?

Comment: `-Wfloat-conversion` in `clang++` and `g++` catches that. You could turn on `-Werror=float-conversion` when compiling as an extra safety guard. If you use `clang++` to compile, you could use `-Weverything` and instead turn off those specific warnings that you don't want. `-Wno-c++98-compat` for example.

Comment: Implicit conversion from `float` to `uint8_t` is definitely fishy, since both sign and value bits could be lost. As for what kind of problems clang-tidy claims to catch, I have no idea.

Comment: Sorry for my c++ comment above - but `-Werror=float-conversion` and `-Weverything` works for C too if you use `clang` or `gcc`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, no I don't. We actually use gnu99 as the C compiler in MCUxpresso and are using clang-tidy as an additional tool, so I wasn't aware that I should add additional flags in the compile command. I wouldn't necessarily call this a pedantic error though right? It loses sign and value.

Comment: That's a clang-tidy option... https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines-narrowing-conversions.html

Comment: @TedLyngmo that definitely seems to work! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Imara Cool, glad it worked! Cheers!

Comment: hehehe your're right @chux-ReinstateMonica, I edited the question, off course this was paraphrasing my code a bit, it wasn't actually 10.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica ah ok! I misunderstood what you meant. No I didn't, because these values aren't actually rounded up numbers. I edited my example as suggested, so I suppose turning on pedantic mode won't work.

Comment: lmara, Note with `float value = 3.4;` you have injected a new [conversion issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66631288/2410359).  Suggest `float value = 3.4f;` to focus on the key issue of the post.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Nice Q&A!

Comment: You are super right @chux-ReinstateMonica, thanks!