# Is the letter "f" necessary if the decimal point is written?

Tags: c, floating-point, constants, preprocessor-directive, xc16

What is the difference between the 2 following code lines?

`#define F_SAMP 10000.0f`

`#define F_SAMP 10000.0`

Aren't both float? (By the way, in this particular case compiler is XC16 but I do not think that matters too much)
Thanks for the attention

Comment: The compiler doesn't matter here - according to the documentation, XC16 uses the normal size of 32 bits for single precision, and 64 bits for double precision. However, if you were using XC8, it would be different, because it uses a truncated version of single-precision floats. See https://microchipdeveloper.com/c:understanding-floating-point-representations

Answer (score 5):

> Is the letter "f" necessary if the decimal point is written?

Not necessary, but best to use `f`-less constants with `double` variables/math and `f` suffixed constants with `float` ones.

> Aren't both float?

There are both *floating-point*.
But `float` and `double` are different.

**Type difference**

Appending an `f` make a floating point constant type `float` rather than `double`.

This can steer to different code with `_Generic` and `<tgmath.h>` as well as the math used in a floating-point expression.

Given the usual range and precision difference, subtle and sometimes not so subtle differences will occur.

**Value difference**

The `f` tell the compiler to use the usually narrower range and precision of a `float`.
e.g. `0.1 != 0.1f`.

[Sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66631288/2410359) it makes a value difference too, even when assigned to a `float.`

Answer (score 5):

Floating-point constants with an `f` or `F` suffix have type `float`, with no suffix have type `double`, and with an `l` or `L` suffix have type `long double`.

First, this makes a difference because the value can be different, and usually will be different if the value is not an integer. For example, using the formats most commonly used for `float` and `double`, the value of `123456789.` is 123,456,789, but the value of `123456789.f` is 123,456,792.

Further, if the value is assigned to a `float`, the result may be different than if the constant used `f` originally. For example, after:

```
float f0 = 9007198986305535.5f;
float f1 = 9007198986305535.5;
```

The value of `f0` is 9,007,198,717,870,080, but the value of `f1` is 9,007,199,254,740,992. This is because the former rounds 9,007,198,986,305,535.5 directly to `float`, but the latter rounds first to `double` and then to `float`.

Answer (score 4):

The `f` suffix makes the constant `10000.0f` have type `float`.

The constant `10000.0` has type `double`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not 100% sure for XC16 but in general omitting the trailing `f` will result in your floating point number to be interpreted by the compiler as a `double`. The `f` is to specifically tell the compiler it is looking at a `float`.

Answer (score 3):

A floating-point constant with an `f` or `F` suffix is of type `float`.

A floating-point constant with no suffix is of type `double`.

A floating-point constant with a suffix of `l` or `L` is of type `long double`.

These are the three distinct floating-point types. (Depending on the implementation, they may or may not have three distinct representations. For example, it's not uncommon for `double` and `long double` to have the same size and representation.)

In the particular case of `10000.0` vs. `10000.0f`, it *probably* doesn't make much difference. Smallish whole number values like 10000.0 can usually be represented exactly in all three floating-point types, so any implicit or explicit conversions won't lose any information. But it's still a good idea to use a type that matches the context in which it's going to be used.

Note that if you omit the decimal point, `10000` is an integer constant (of type `int`), and `10000f` is a syntax error. A floating-point context, with or without a suffix must have either a decimal point or an exponent.

This is a simpler set of rules than the ones for integer constants, where there are more distinct types, more suffixes, and the type of a constant can depend on its value.