# Why when using printf float and double show the same number of digits?

Tags: c, types, floating-point, double

I wanted to see the difference in how many digits i get when using float and when using double but i get the same results

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float x=1.2222222222222222f;
    printf("%f %d", x,sizeof(x)); // This is what it prints out 1.222222 4
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double x=1.2222222222222222;  
    printf("%f %d", x,sizeof(x));  // This is what it prints out 1.222222 8
    return 0;
}
```

It prints out the same value even tho double is obviously double the size and should save more digits. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Any smaller floating point type is promoted to `double` when passing to a function with variable arguments list like `printf`. You will only see a difference if the values you assign get rounded differently for `float` and `double`.

Comment: `"%f"` is equivalent to `"%.6f"` [C11 7.21.6.1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1): "f,F: ... If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6 ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` returns `size_t`. To print `size_t` you need `%zu` instead of `%d`

If you want to see the real difference between `float` and `double` you need to print more digits using `%.NUMBERf`

Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float x=1.2222222222222222f;
    printf("%.70f %zu\n", x,sizeof(x)); 
    double y=1.2222222222222222;  
    printf("%.70f %zu\n", y,sizeof(y)); 
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1.2222222089767456054687500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 4
1.2222222222222220988641083749826066195964813232421875000000000000000000 8
```

Comment: we use zu because sizeof return a size_t. The z is needed because size_t is an unsigned that can have different dimension. But what is the size_t dimension dependent on? Also from  what i read when i write for example `float x=17.4` x will be a double and to explicitly get a float i should write `float x=17.4f` . But when i printed the two cases i got the same results, as if they were both float??

Comment: @Foch29 Using an `f` suffix with `float = (some FP constant)` vs. `float = (some FP constant)f` rarely, but sometimes makes a value [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66631288/2410359).

Answer (score 0):

> It prints out the same value even tho double is obviously double the size and should save more digits.

When passing a `float` as a `...` argument in `printf()`, it is first promoted to a `double`.  `"%f"` prints that `double` to a rounded 6 places after the `.`.

Since the original values do not differ when rounded to 6 places after the decimal point, they appear the same.

> What am i doing wrong?

Expecting the default precision of 6 is insufficient to distinguish.

---

Easiest to see different with `"%a"`.

```
printf("%a\n", 1.2222222222222222);
printf("%a\n", 1.2222222222222222f);

0x1.38e38e38e38e3p+0
0x1.38e38ep+0
```

or with sufficient decimal places in exponential notation.

```
printf("%.*e\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, 1.2222222222222222);
printf("%.*e\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, 1.2222222222222222f);

1.2222222222222221e+00
1.2222222089767456e+00
```