# VS code is showing different answer for two same code

Tags: c

I run two same code. But it shows different answer.

Code 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    float far = 98.6;

    printf("%f", (far-32)*5/9);

    return 0;

}
```

Code 2:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    float far = 98.6;

    float cel;

    cel = (far-32)*5/9;

    printf("%f", cel);

    return 0;

}
```

First code gives 36.99999 as output and second code gives 37.00000 as output.

Comment: first one uses `double` math and the second one rounds to `float`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2):

Research `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.  This reports the intermediate floating-point math allowed.

```
printf("%d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
```

When this is non-zero, the 2 codes may have different output as `printf("%f", (far-32)*5/9);` can print the result of `(far-32)*5/9` using `double` or `float` math.

In the 2nd case, `(far-32)*5/9);` is performed user `float` or `double` and then saved as a `float` and then printed.  Its promotion to a `double` as  part of a `printf()` ... argument does not affect the value.

---

For deeper understanding, print `far, cel, (far-32)*5/9` with `"%a"` and `"%.17g"` for greater detail.

---

In both cases, `far` is the `float` value `0x1.8a6666p+6` or `98.599998474121094...`

As I see it the first used `double` math in `printf("%f", (far-32)*5/9);` and the second used `double` math too, yet rounded to a `float` result from `cel = (far-32)*5/9;`.  To be certain we need to see the intermediate results as suggested above.

---

Avoid `double` constants with `float` objects.  It [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66631288/2410359) makes a difference.

```
// float far = 98.6;
float far = 98.6f;
```

Use `double` objects as a default.  Save `float` for select speed/space cases. [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74603690/2410359).

Comment: The fact that for `printf` the format specifier `%f` is accepted both for float and double doesn't help. If it was required to use `%lf` for double, as is the case with `scanf`, the first case would lead to a warning, which would hint at what is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

The difference lies in the types used and the `printf` call.

Variable-argument functions like `printf` will *promote* arguments of smaller types. So for example a `float` argument will be promoted to `double`.

The type `double` have much higher precision than `float`.

Since in the first program you do the calculation as part of the actual `printf` call, not storing the result in a variable using less precision, the compiler might perform the whole calculation using `double` and increasing the precision. Precision that will be lost when you store the result in `cel` in the second example.

Unless you have very specific requirements, you should generally always use `double` for all your floating-point variables and values and calculations.

Comment: "a float argument will be promoted to double" is true, yet that is after `(far-32)*5/9)` is calculated.  There are other mechanisms in play that can cause `(far-32)*5/9)` to calculate as `double` other than the `...` arguments of `printf()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Hmm, didn't know about `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`. I only read about [the usual arithmetic conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions), which basically says that there's no float-to-double promotion for floating-point operations. +1 :)