# How to define a double constant in C?

Tags: c

How to define a double constant in C ?

For float is like so:

```
#define powerFactor 1.00f
```

For double i dont know:

```
#define energy 55639.00xx
```

Should `xx` be `d`, `ld`, `lf`, nothing or compiler specific?

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "Before posting a question, we strongly recommend that you spend a reasonable amount of time researching the problem and searching for existing questions on this site that may provide an answer."  So, what research did you do?

Comment: Consider taking a look at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)

Comment: Hint: why do you need to append `f` for a `float` literal? What would happen without it?

Comment: @Andrew Henle, I searched all over google and couldn't find it, and here too.

Comment: What makes you think you need to add something on the end? Does `10` need something on the end to be an `int`? Anyway, `#define` just does token substitutions, and is not related to the syntax of C.

Comment: @jamesdlin, i am converting to bytes to send over a socket, and, for tests purposes. i only want to learn the right way to do it too.

Comment: @Blackgaurd not the best source. There are no "floating point literals" in `C` language.  Only string literals and compound literals

Comment: @Blackgaurd Wrong reference. That's for C++. This is the [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant).

Comment: @jamesdlin "What would happen without it?" --> You may enjoy:  [When does appending an 'f' change the value of a floating constant when assigned to a `float`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66631288/2410359).

Answer (score 2):

In C `double` doesn't have a suffix, according to the C17 standard chapter 6.4.4.2 paragraph 4. A floating point literal without a suffix will be of type `double`:

```
#define energy 55639.00
```

There are also other situations where `double` is assumed to be the "default" floating point type. For example the math functions would have no suffix for double arguments (`sin`), and would have other suffixes for other types (e.g. `sinf` for float); `printf` (but not `scanf`) will assume `double` by default too.

Comment: Aside: `scanf()` is not a `double` vs. `float` issue, but a `double *` vs. `float *` one.

Comment: Also, the `double` type is actually used when a `float` type is passed as a variadic parameter.  The floating-point `printf` conversion specifiers `%f`, `%g` and `%e`, unless told otherwise, accept `double` arguments:  `%f` means fixed, not `foat`.

Answer (score 2):

> How to define a double constant in C?
> Should xx be d, ld, lf, nothing or compiler specific?

"nothing"
For compliant C compilers, a *floating-point constant* without a suffix is type `double`.

Answer (score 1):

To be 100% sure that it will be double:

```
#define energy ((double)55639.00L)
```

Some compilers have a command line option to treat float point constants without suffixes as `float` not `double`. For example gcc `-fsingle-precision-constant`

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Whether I do `printf("%.15f\n", 3.141592653589793);` or `printf("%.15f\n", (double)3.141592653589793);` with that compiler option, the result is still `3.141592741012573`. If, however, I put an `L` on there for a _long_ double, then it works. Though you need the `(double)` in that case. `printf("%.15f\n", (double)3.14159265358979323L);` with that option gives `3.141592653589793`. gcc really should have a non-standard suffix for doubles to go along with that non-standard option.

Comment: @MarkAdler amended

Comment: All you're doing is making that command line option useless. The command line option changes the language into a nonstandard C dialect. Coding defensively so that your code works the same in nonstandard dialects is a fool's errand except in narrowly boxed circumstances.

Comment: @Kaz dejure ISO/IEC 9899:2018 is the Standard, defacto gcc is the Standard.

Comment: Firstly, gcc isn't any kind of standard because a churning mess cannot be considered a standard. Secondly, only gcc **invoked without obscure code generation (or even diagnostic) options** could possibly be a *de jure* language standard. I.e. the language "GNU C" could possibly be a de facto standard.  With suitable options, GCC can reject `(A && B || C)` as an error. That doesn't make it a de facto standard that this construct is incorrect.