# How to validate numbers in my program?(From a complete newbie in C coding)

Tags: c

So for my CompSci intro class we were tasked with creating a program that can calculate the average speed of something after *distance(a positive number not exceeding 5000)* and *time(also a positive number not exceeding 5000)* were input into the console. Problem is, I'm a complete shitter and I couldn't find a tutorial on google how to validate my numbers so my program knows when an invalid input was entered.

**For main criteria of my program: I can't code in any hard values, and I cannot use global defines or variables.**

(Yes I know it looks p bad rn but that's why asking for help is so nice.)

```
int main()

{

  const float speed200 = 200.0, speed30 = 30.0, speed5 = 5.0;
  float uDistance =  0.0, uTime = 0.0, Uspeed = 0.0;
  

  printf("\nEnter a distance traveled (positive number not exceeding 5000 miles) ");
  scanf("%f", &uDistance);
  printf("\nEnter a time (positive number not exceeding 5000 hours) ");
  scan("%f", &uTime);



  uSpeed= uDistance / uTime


  if(uSpeed > speed200)
  {
     printf("The air looking mad airey today");
  }
  else if(uSpeed > speed30);
  {
     printf("5 dollars per gallon is a joke!");
  }
  else if(uSpeed > speed5);
  {
    printf("Alwyas wear a helmet on your bicycle!");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Look both ways before crossing!");
  }
  

  return 0;

}
```

I haven't really tried anything yet cause I'm terrified of goofing up the code to clown status and google wasn't being helpful. I would've just looked at the lecture outline but my professor hasn't gotten to posting it yet.

Comment: Welcome! The first step in validating input is to check that `scanf` *returns* the number of items you expect to be scanned. For example `if(scanf("%f", &uDistance) != 1) { /* handle error */ }` . The second step is to check the range of the value. For example `if(uDistance < 1 || uDistance > 5000) ...`. BTW it's best if you copy/paste actual code that compiles, instead of an approximation – it matters :)

Comment: Once you've verified `scanf` has done what you expected, then use `if (uDistance > ... && uDistance < ...) { ... }` to verify the input is within the correct range.

Comment: "5 dollars per gallon is a joke!" --> Some states [joke](https://www.npr.org/2022/06/06/1103318977/states-highest-gas-prices).

Comment: @Brazen General, "For main criteria of my program: I can't code in any hard values, and I cannot use global defines or variables." --> Defines are never global.  They only affect code generation from their point of definition to the end of file being compiled - not the entire emitted code.  There are not _global_ like an object can be global concerning scope and lifetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the criteria along with your initial coding, the criteria of not allowing hard values or constants seems to conflict with the fact that there are hard-coded constant values such as "speed5 = 5.0".  So working around that vagueness, my suggestion would be to pass your "5000" limit as a program call parameter which can be done.

Due to the need for additional testing of the "scanf" statements as noted in the good comments, and also performing rudimentary syntax cleanup with the provided code, it was simplest to present the refactored code in full as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)                      /* Ensuring that the proper number of parameters are entered */
    {
        printf("Please enter the limit value\n");
        return -1;
    }

    float speed200 = 200.0, speed30 = 30.0, speed5 = 5.0;
    float uDistance =  0.0, uTime = 0.0, uSpeed = 0.0;

    int limit = atoi(argv[1]);          /* Limit introduced as a program call parameter */

    while (1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a distance traveled (positive number not exceeding %d miles) ", limit);
        if(scanf("%f", &uDistance) < 1) /* Testing scanf to ensure something was entered */
            return -1;

        if (uDistance > 0 && uDistance < limit)
            break;

        printf("An invalid distance value was entered - try again\n");
    }

    while (1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a time (positive number not exceeding %d hours) ", limit);
        if(scanf("%f", &uTime) < 1)     /* Testing scanf to ensure something was entered */
            return -1;

        if (uTime > 0 && uTime < limit)
                break;

        printf("An invalid time value was entered - try again\n");
    }

    uSpeed = uDistance / uTime;

    if(uSpeed > speed200)
    {
        printf("The air looking mad airey today\n");
    }
    else if(uSpeed > speed30)
    {
        printf("5 dollars per gallon is a joke!\n");
    }
    else if(uSpeed > speed5)
    {
        printf("Always wear a helmet on your bicycle!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Look both ways before crossing!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The key items to note in this refactored code are:

- The usage of input parameters in the call of the "main" function which can be analyzed in any good C programming tutorial book.
- The additional testing of the "scanf" input to ensure proper input of data.
- The additional testing of valid input ranges for speed and time inside of "while" loops to provide the validation that evidently is sought for this exercise.

Following were a couple of tests at the terminal with this refactored code.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/AverageSpeed/bin/Release$ ./AverageSpeed
Please enter the limit value
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/AverageSpeed/bin/Release$ ./AverageSpeed "5000"

Enter a distance traveled (positive number not exceeding 5000 miles) 200

Enter a time (positive number not exceeding 5000 hours) 5
5 dollars per gallon is a joke!
```

As always, there often are many ways to address a coding assignment such as this and this is just one such way.  But go ahead and review it to see if it provides food for thought in attacking your assignment.

Answer (score 1):

> how to validate my numbers so my program knows when an invalid input was entered(?)

- Read user input into an ample sized buffer as a *string*.
- Parse the string into the number using `strtof()`, `sscanf()`, etc.
- Look for non-numeric input as well as out of range values.
- Best handled as a helper function.
- Advanced: Append `f` to floating point constants used to initialize `float`s to avoid [double rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66631288/2410359).
- Avoid naked magic numbers.  Use a macro for the constant.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FLT_STRING_SIZE (FLT_MAX_10_EXP + 10) // Handle largest FLOAT and then some

float read_float(const char *prompt, float min, float max) {
  float val;
  for (;;) {
    fprintf(stdout, prompt);
    char buf[FLT_STRING_SIZE * 2 + 1]; // Generously allow for input even wider input
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // No more input available.
    }
    char *endptr;
    errno = 0;
    val = strtof(buf, &endptr);
    if (buf == endptr) {
      // Non-numeric input
      continue;
    }
    // Usually errno having a non-zero value is not a concern here.
    if (errno) {
      ; // TBD code to handle pedantic concerns.
    }
    // Look for trailing non-numeric junk
    while (isspace(*((unsigned char* ) endptr))) {
      endptr++;
    }
    if (*endptr) {
      // Non-numeric input trailing junk
      continue;
    }
    if (!(val >= min && val <= max)) {
      // Out of range
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }
  return val;
}

#define DIST_PROMPT "\nEnter a distance traveled (positive number not exceeding 5000 miles) "
#define DIST_MIN FLT_TRUE_MIN
#define DIST_MAX 5000.0f
#define TIME_PROMPT "\nEnter a time (positive number not exceeding 5000 hours) "
#define TIME_MIN FLT_TRUE_MIN
#define TIME_MAX 5000.0f

int main(void) {
  float uDistance = read_float(DIST_PROMPT, DIST_MIN, DIST_MAX);
  float uTime     = read_float(TIME_PROMPT, TIME_MIN, TIME_MAX);

  float uSpeed= uDistance / uTime;
  if(uSpeed > speed200) {
  ...
```