# why is the hexadecimal value of a float typecasted into an integer different from the float's actual hexadecimal value

Tags: c, pointers, casting, bit, ieee-754

Why are the hexadecimal values printed by the program different from each other knowing that the binary representation of both -12.342 (float) and the value stored in bi is the same ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float bf = -12.342;
    int bi = *(int *)&bf;
    float rbf = *(float *)&bi;
    printf("%X %p\n", bf, &bf);
    printf("%X %p\n", bi, &bi);
    printf("%X %p\n", rbf, &rbf);
    return 0;
}
```

Understand the underlying conversions in C.

Comment: The program has undefined behavior since you use `%X` (which expects an `unsigned int`) for printing `double`s (yes). You should also cast the pointers to `void*` when using `printf`.

Comment: It also has undefined behavior because both `int bi = *(int*) &bf;` and `float rbf = *(float*) &bi;` are [strict aliasing violations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Comment: Use `memcpy()` if you want to copy the binary representation of the float to an int.

Comment: You forgot to show the output of the program.

Comment: In some ABI's, integer and floating point parameters are passed to function calls in different registers, so the output you are getting from `printf` is pretty meaningless because the types of the function arguments to not match the types that the function is expecting.

Comment: Basically, the question should be "why is undefined behavior undefined?"

Comment: It's fun to explore the power of C with its type casting freedom and such.   But a float is typically a 4-byte array, and has a mantissa(23 bits), which contains the value of the number, and an exponent(8 bits), which contains the order of magnitude of the number.  Maybe if you only targeted the mantissa portion of the array via casting, you could occasionally get a value  that matched what you assigned to the float.   But it is a futile exercise, except for "wow" value.  Similarly, you could bitmask out the exponent, and occasionally get a matching value when comparing to its integer version.

Comment: @Fallendo, Tip: save time and enable all compiler warnings.  With "'-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wconversion' " I got many warnings including  ".warning: conversion from 'double' to 'float' changes value from '-1.2342000000000001e+1' to '-1.2342e+1f' [-Wfloat-conversion]
warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
warning: format '%X' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
printf("%X %p\n",bf, &bf);

Answer (score 2):

`float` values are promoted to `double` values when arguments to variadric functions such as `printf`. So you are passing a `double`, but an `unsigned int` is expected by `%X`. So while `int` and `float` might have the same size for you, that's apparently not the case for `int` and `double`.

Fixing that gives sensible results.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void dump( void *p, size_t n ) {
   char *cp = p;
   while ( n-- )
      printf( "%02hhX", *(cp++) );

   printf( "\n" );
}

int main( void ) {
   printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( float ) );
   printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( int ) );

   float bf  = -12.342;
   int   bi  = *(int*)&bf;
   float rbf = *(float*)&bi;

   dump( &bf,  sizeof( bf  ) );
   dump( &bi,  sizeof( bi  ) );
   dump( &rbf, sizeof( rbf ) );
}
```

```
4
4
D57845C1
D57845C1
D57845C1
```

(Remember that the bytes are "backwards" on a little-endian machine.)

`int bi = *(int*)&bf;` and `float rbf = *(float*)&bi;` is still all kinds of wrong. But we're just exploring, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Using the **System V Application Binary Interface AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement** as an example ABI for illustrative purposes (other ABIs will pass arguments to functions differently):

1. For `printf("%X %p\n",bf, &bf);`, the first argument (the pointer to the format specifier string literal) will be passed in the `%rdi` register because it is the first argument in the INTEGER class (because pointers are in the INTEGER class as far as this ABI is concerned), the second argument (the value of `bf` after conversion to `double`) will be passed in the `%xmm0` register because it is the first argument in the SSE class, and the third argument (the pointer to `bf`) will be passed in the `%rsi` register because it is the second argument in the INTEGER class. However, the `printf` function is expecting the first parameter to be a pointer in the `%rdi` register (OK), the second parameter to be an `unsigned int` in the `%rsi` register (WRONG register!), and the third parameter to be a pointer in the `%rdx` register (WRONG register!). Because values are in the wrong registers, the output is not as expected.
2. For `printf("%X %p\n",bi, &bi);`, the first argument (the pointer to the format specifier string literal) will be passed in the `%rdi` register because it is the first argument in the INTEGER class, the second argument (the value of `bi`) will be passed in the `%rsi` register because it is the second argument in the INTEGER class, and the third argument (the pointer to `bi`) will be passed in the `%rdx` register because it is the third argument in the INTEGER class. The parameters are all in the registers that the `printf` function expects to find them, so the output is OK (ignoring subtleties such as passing an `int` when an `unsigned int` was expected, and a `int *` when a `void *` was expected, that the implementation does not really care about).
3. For `printf("%X %p\n",rbf, &rbf);`, the situation is the same as for `printf("%X %p\n",bf, &bf);`.

`printf` is declared to be called with a variable number of arguments after the format string argument (i.e. after the first argument). Those are the *variadic* arguments. The only conversions done to the variadic arguments are the *default argument promotions*, converting any integer typed value narrower than `int` to `int`, and any `float` value to `double`. `printf` uses the format string to determine the expected type of each of the variadic arguments, and the ABI determines where to find arguments of different types. Any mismatch between the expected type of each variadic argument, and the actual type of the argument (after default argument promotions) will result in *undefined behavior*.

Other undefined behavior in the code is due to breaking the strict aliasing rules in expressions such as `*(int*) &bf`.

Answer (score 0):

> why is the hexadecimal value of a float ...?

Consider stepping back a bit and rather than printing the "hexadecimal" value with OP's non-portable code or byte dump (other good answers), consider using `"%a"`, `"%A"` to print in a standard hex-like output.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float bf = -12.342f;
    printf("%.*g\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, bf);
    printf("%a\n", bf);
    printf("%A\n", bf);
}

-12.342
-0x1.8af1aap+3
-0X1.8AF1AAP+3
            ^^ Decimal power-of-2 exponent
   ^^^^^^^^    Hexadecimal significand
^              Sign
```

Notice how nicely the 23 most significant bits of *8AF1AA* are *4578D5* and match the fraction of a [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) encoding.

---

- Enable all warnings to save time.
- Minor: rather than initializing a `float` with a `double` constant.  Use a `float` constant. [Sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66631288/2410359) it makes a difference.

```
    // float bf = -12.342;
    float bf = -12.342f;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code posted has multiple counts of undefined behavior:

- both `int bi = *(int *)&bf;` and `float rbf = *(float *)&bi;` violate the strict aliasing rule: you cannot reinterpret the memory contents of a variable as a different type this way. You should use `memcpy` to copy the bytes of the `float` representation into that of the `int` variable and vice versa.
- Passing `bf` for a `%X` conversion has undefined behavior: the `float` value `bf` is implicitly converted to a `double` as passed to `printf` is a way that may be completely different from passing an `int` value.  The behavior is undefined, anything can happen, including random output.
- Passing `bi` for a `%X` conversion is not strictly correct: the expected type is `unsigned int`. This is less of a problem but if the `int` value is negative, the output is undefined.
- Passing `rbf` for a `%X` conversion has undefined behavior, see above.
- Passing `&bf`, `&bi` and `&rbf` for a `%p` conversion is also undefined behavior. You should cast these pointers as `(void *)` as `%p` expects a `void *`. This should not be a issue in most environments, but the cast is recommended.

Note also these remarks:

- `float bf = -12.342;` performs an implicit `double` to `float` conversion.
- passing `float` values to `printf` transparently converts the `float` value to `double` and passes the `double` value.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    float bf = -12.342f;
    int bi;
    float rbf;

    memcpy(&bi, &bf, sizeof bi);
    memcpy(&rbf, &bi, sizeof rbf);

    printf(" bf: %p  %a %.3f\n", (void *)&bf, bf, bf);
    printf(" bi: %p  %X\n", (void *)&bi, bi);
    printf("rbf: %p  %a %.3f\n", (void *)&rbf, rbf, rbf);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 bf: 0x30d148314  -0x1.8af1aap+3 -12.342
 bi: 0x30d148318  C14578D5
rbf: 0x30d14831c  -0x1.8af1aap+3 -12.342
```

The output for `bf` and `rbf` is identical, which is the least one would expect given that the bytes of both variables are identical by construction, assuming `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`.

Note however that there is one more possible case of undefined in the above code as the C Standard allows for these types to have padding bits and trap values: reading the `int` value of `bi` thus initialized may have undefined behavior if the `float` representation of `-12.342f` happens to be a trap value for the `int` `bi`.  It would take a perverse implementation to produce an actual problem for this code, but it is technically possible on a [DS9K](https://en-academic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/2748465).