# When are implicit floating-point promotions something to warn about?

Tags: c++, floating-point

My C++ compiler (Clang with `-Wdouble-promotion`) warns about implicit floating-point conversions, as in

```
some_long_double_value() > 1.0
```

While I understand that the double constant `1.0` is implicitly converted to a `long double` value for the sake of comparison, I don't see why this is something to warn about.

I understand that implicit floating-point conversion might be undesirable in some situations, such as, say, overload resolution. But I think for the sake of comparison this is completely harmless. Or am I missing something here, such as a border case or special hardware situations?

Comment: What are your warning settings?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Promotion warnings are all about performance.  Whether they are really useful depends on your application and its performance needs.  The performance penalty also depends on the target CPU.

Comment: If you don't want the warning... don't use it.

Comment: @NicolBolas: that's the point, I'd like to learn whether I should use it.

Comment: Use literals of correct type; `1.0L` for `long double`, `1.0` for `double`, and `1.0F` for `float`.

Comment: The motivation for the warning was initially for when a `float` was promoted to `double` and gcc has this description:

_"CPUs with a 32-bit “single-precision” floating-point unit implement `float` in hardware, but emulate double in software. On such a machine, doing computations using `double` values is much more expensive because of the overhead required for software emulation"_.

Comment: It might also be a warning to avoid subtle bugs. e.g. not passing the value of pi with enough precission resulting in unecessary numerical errors.

Comment: @TedLyngmo which early hardware that GCC was implemented on only had 32 bit hardware implementations of FP arithmetic?  ISTR some CDC machines had 60bit floats back in the day.  On PCs x87 had 80bit long double from the outset but as an optional extra chip so that *all* FP instructions were emulated by default. Doubles and long doubles were very much slower. MicroSoft C stopped supporting true long doubles after Ver 6.0 (annoying). Promotion is fairly harmless and can still be used today to save memory bandwidth. It is always exact for integers. Rounding down from double *to* float is dodgy.

Comment: @MartinBrown _"which early hardware that GCC was implemented on only had 32 bit hardware implementations of FP arithmetic?"_ - I didn't dig deeper and copied gcc's motivation straight from their homepage.

Comment: A key consideration when writing serious code (algorithms, etc) involving floating point is performance, and implicit promotions can hurt that.   Such warnings are a heads-up to the programmer that something unintended may be happening that can affect performance.   When floating point performance really matters, there are always approaches available to make the programmer's intent explicit (which either eliminate implicit promotions or - if that's the intent - replacing them with explicit conversions - either way, an incidental effect is to eliminate warnings about implicit promotions).

Comment: Of course, an alternative (for those using floating point casually, in cases where performance doesn't matter) it is possible to disable such warnings.     That can be problematical in projects that have some code where floating point performance is critical  (since the people writing performance critical code don't want to simply disable such warnings, people using floating point for non-critical stuff tend to complain when their code elicits warnings, and sometimes those folks do edit the same source files in a project).

Answer (score 0):

> When are implicit floating-point promotions something to warn about?

When the code's literal has different values as a `double` vs. `long double`, code will have different functionality.  By using matching types in the compare, it is more likely the intended code and not a causal error.

Consider a different value than 1.0.

```
some_long_double_value() > 0.1 
// versus
some_long_double_value() > 0.1L
```

Literals from decimal text may have different values as `(long double) 0.1` is not certainly the same as `0.1L`.

Sample:

```
0.1  --> 0x1.999999999999ap-4
0.1L --> 0x1.999999999999999ap-4
```

---

Related: [When does appending an 'f' change the value of a floating constant when assigned to a `float`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66631288/2410359).

---

If truly code needs to compare a `long double` against a `double`, be explicit.  Use a cast, or something more C++-ish.  Consider commenting such code as even with the cast, it looks amiss.

```
some_long_double_value() > (long double) 0.1  /* Cast used intentionally */
```

---

Other concerns exist about implicit floating-point promotions (like code steering), yet this is a key one for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this `-Wdouble-promotion` warning was added (first in GCC, then in Clang) is exclusively for performance. See the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wno-double-promotion), which says:

> Give a warning when a value of type `float` is implicitly promoted to `double`. CPUs with a 32-bit “single-precision” floating-point unit implement `float` in hardware, but emulate `double` in software. On such a machine, doing computations using `double` values is much more expensive because of the overhead required for software emulation.

and also

> It is easy to accidentally do computations with `double` because floating-point literals are implicitly of type `double`.

The latter point is interesting. This explains why GCC warns for the `float`-to-`double` promotion (`f` and `g` below, at least up to GCC 13), but not for the `double`-to-`long double` promotion, contrary to Clang, which warns for both (`f`, `g` and `h` below, at least up to Clang 17).

FYI, about the introduction of this warning in Clang (also for performance reasons):

- https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15109
- https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20151026/142080.html

```
int f (double x) { return x > 1.0f; }
int g (float x) { return x > 1.0; }
int h (long double x) { return x > 1.0; }
```

Note that the warning is mostly interesting for `g`, which corresponds to the above remark about floating-point literals, as this one is probably accidental. So I think that only the `g` case should warn, because for `f` and `h`, one cannot improve the performance anyway.

If there is an intent to warn about the different precisions, then GCC is inconsistent. But I think that this should be a separate warning, because one may not want to warn when the promotion of a constant does not alter its value (such as in the `1.0` case).